# Passing function pointer to arg of pthread_create function

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, function-pointers

I have a function `void startScanner(...)` taking two function pointer as arguments: `userType *vConfig(void)` and `void * vCallback(void)`. In this function i would like to create a thread and call `vCallback()` function in the function thread created. So i decided to pass vCallback as args to pthreadcreate.
The code of startScanner function :

```
void startScanner(tUsrStatus (*vConfig)(), void* (vCallback)()){

    if(pthread_create(&scannerThread, NULL, scannerThreadFunc, vCallback))
    {
        printf("Thread creation fails!\n");
    }
}
```

The scannerTread function:

```
static void *scannerThreadFunc(void *arg()){

    void *funcptr(void) = arg;

    while(1)
    {
        funcptr();
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: function ‘funcptr’ is initialized like a variable
error: nested function ‘funcptr’ declared but never defined
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you see any difference between your second argument in the first snippet and you `funcptr` decl in your second snippet. Hmm.... (hint: recheck your syntax of `arg` too). I'm nearly certain *all* of those cases should be `void *(*varname)(void)`. That is, if you are passing an address of a function that (a) returns `void*`, and (b) accepts no arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Syntax errors aside (*) , it's **impossible** in standard C to pass a function pointer in a `void *`. There's a fundamental difference between pointers to functions and pointers to data, they can't be converted into each other. This is because there might be platforms where function and data pointers would differ even in size, or refer to different address spaces, or whatever.

But of course, there's a simple way to achieve what you want: Put your function pointer inside a `struct` and pass a pointer to that.

```
typedef (*callback)(void);

typedef struct threadargs
{
    callback cb;
} threadargs;

void mycallback(void)
{
    // ...
}

void *threadfunc(void *arg)
{
    threadargs *ta = arg;

    // call your callback:
    ta->cb();

    return ta; // or: return 0, or some pthread_exit(), ...
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    threadargs ta = { mycallback };
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, threadfunc, &ta);

    // make sure "ta" lives for as long as the thread executes,
    // here just wait until it exits:
    pthread_join(&thread, 0);
}
```

add error checking etc.

---

(*) as for the concrete error you're getting, a function pointer needs parantheses around the identifier, so instead of

```
void *funcptr(void) = arg;
```

you'd have to write

```
void (*funcptr)(void) = arg;
```

To facilitate the usage of function pointers, it's common to `typedef` them, as seen in my example above. Anyways, as explained above, this wouldn't solve your problem here.

Comment: No need to create a special struct, it's enough to pass a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @n.m. maybe I misread the question, I was under the impression that the ultimate goal was to pass **two** pointers. Anyways, a struct doesn't hurt and is the generic solution.

Comment: Thanks Felix, i write it in this way. there is no longer compilation issue but i have a SIGSEGV sigmentation fault when it try to execute the callback function "ta -> cb()". Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/LDistHye

Comment: @julesconté see my comment "*make sure "ta" lives for as long as the thread executes*". You don't in your code. One option would be to declare it `static`, it depends on your usecase.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, it works with static déclaration. But is there the best way to implement callback function in the function thread?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. It's good practice in general to define a `struct` containing data your thread needs. How you instantiate that struct really depends on your usecase. Automatic storage duration (as a local variable) would be best if the function creating the thread isn't left as long as the thread is running. You might want to read on storage durations in C in general ...

Comment: Ok i understand. Thank you a lot!